# Remove duplicate values from queue

Tags: c#, queue

I have an exrecise on which i have to write a method which get Queue and remove each part of it who`s in the queue more than once for example: for 11223344
It wil return a queue with 1234

How can i do it?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`Distinct()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb348436(v=vs.100).aspx) function of an `IEnumerable`:

```
Queue<int> a = new Queue<int>(); // This is the queue from which you want to remove duplicates.
Queue<int> result = new Queue<int>(a.Distinct());
```

<sub>A [Queue](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7977ey2c(v=vs.110).aspx) is essentially a collection, thus an IEnumerable and hence the LINQ extension methods for IEnumerable types</sub> <sup>can be called.</sup>

---

Here's a demo : [.NET Fiddle Link](https://dotnetfiddle.net/01M5Ot)

Answer (score 0):

This is basically a duplication:

- [The Most Efficient Implementation of UniqueQueue and UniqueReplacementQueue Collections in .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6464531/the-most-efficient-implementation-of-uniquequeue-and-uniquereplacementqueue-coll)
- [How to remove duplicate items from a queue within a time frame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4947869/how-to-remove-duplicate-items-from-a-queue-within-a-time-frame)

Depending on you input:

- if you have a sorted integer queue, you dequeue each element and
  queue it only once. When you're back to the first integer (lower than
  previous), you stop.
- use a hashtable/dictionary as temporary storage to efficiently find duplicates.
- a simple solution (not most efficient and needs quite a lot temporary memory and would be bad if you have several millions of elements in your queue) would be to use Linq like new Queue(queueWithDuplicates.Distinct());

More reads of how distinct works:
   [How does LINQ .distinct method sort?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4109938/how-does-linq-distinct-method-sort)